# Backbone.js: How to determine what action triggered an event?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

While using backbone I was really happy that a `request` event appeared when started to do any kind of request. Now I know that after successful request a `sync` event is triggered on a model but I was wondering if it's possible to know what kind of action happened exactly, i.e. whether the `sync` event was caused by model fetch, create or update. Is there a way to know what action triggered it or should it be extended and overwritten somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this information using the `options` parameter, which will be available in the [event handler(s)](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog).

For example, consider updating a model:

```
model.save(attributes, {action: "update"});
```

Then in your `sync` event handler:

```
onSync: function(model, resp, options) {
    if (options.action == "update") {
        // do something
    }
    else if (options.action == "create") {
        // do something else
    }
},
```